# Issue with staircase affect in all browsers when using inline

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="uft-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></head>scipt?
<![endif]-->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
#container{
margin: auto;
width: 800px;
padding-top: 50px;
}

#menu ul
{
float:left;
width:100%;
padding:0;
margin:0;
list-style-type:none;
position: fixed;
background-color: blue;
top:0;
left:0;
right:0;
margin:0;
overflow:hidden;
}
#menu a
{
float:left;
text-decoration:none;
color:black;
padding:0.2em 0.6em;
border-right:1px solid white;
}
#menu a:hover {color: blue;}

#menu li a {display:inline;}


 </style>
<div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li><br>
                <li><a href="#">Categories</a></li><br>
                <li><a href="admin/index.php">Admin Panel</a></li><br>
                <li><a href="admin/logout.php">Log Out</a></li><br>
             </ul>
</div>



<h2></h2>
 <div id="container">
 <body>

<div id="header">
<h1> Welcome To My Own Personal Blog</h1>
 </div>

<article>
    <hr />
<h4><div id="date">10th<br>Oct</div></h4>
<h2>My Seventh Post</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin nulla neque, adipiscing vitae convallis in, varius vitae enim. Vestibulum sollicitudin eu justo id placerat. Donec viverra vestibulum dictum. Suspendisse potenti. Integer quis dolor luctus diam molestie blandit. Proin tristique lacus nec tellus euismod imperdiet. Fusce gravida in augue<a href='post.php?id=7'> .. Read more</a></p>
<p>Category: Uncatagorised</p>
</article>

<article>
    <hr />
<h4><div id="date">2nd<br>Oct</div></h4>
<h2>My Sixth Post</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin nulla neque, adipiscing vitae convallis in, varius vitae enim. Vestibulum sollicitudin eu justo id placerat. Donec viverra vestibulum dictum. Suspendisse potenti. Integer quis dolor luctus diam molestie blandit. Proin tristique lacus nec tellus euismod imperdiet. Fusce gravida in augue<a href='post.php?id=6'> .. Read more</a></p>
<p>Category: Uncatagorised</p>
</article>

<article>
    <hr />
<h4><div id="date">01st<br>Oct</div></h4>
<h2>My Fifth Post!  </h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin nulla neque, adipiscing vitae convallis in, varius vitae enim. Vestibulum sollicitudin eu justo id placerat. Donec viverra vestibulum dictum. Suspendisse potenti. Integer quis dolor luctus diam molestie blandit. Proin tristique lacus nec tellus euismod imperdiet. Fusce gravida in augue<a href='post.php?id=5'> .. Read more</a></p>
<p>Category: review</p>
</article>

<article>
    <hr />
<h4><div id="date">18th<br>Sept</div></h4>
<h2>My Forth Post!</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin nulla neque, adipiscing vitae convallis in, varius vitae enim. Vestibulum sollicitudin eu justo id placerat. Donec viverra vestibulum dictum. Suspendisse potenti. Integer quis dolor luctus diam molestie blandit. Proin tristique lacus nec tellus euismod imperdiet. Fusce gravida in augue<a href='post.php?id=4'> .. Read more</a></p>
<p>Category: Uncatagorised</p>
</article>

<article>
    <hr />
<h4><div id="date">14th<br>Sept</div></h4>
<h2>My Third Post</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin nulla neque, adipiscing vitae convallis in, varius vitae enim. Vestibulum sollicitudin eu justo id placerat. Donec viverra vestibulum dictum. Suspendisse potenti. Integer quis dolor luctus diam molestie blandit. Proin tristique lacus nec tellus euismod imperdiet. Fusce gravida in augue<a href='post.php?id=3'> .. Read more</a></p>
<p>Category: review</p>
</article>

<article>
    <hr />
<h4><div id="date">12th<br>Sept</div></h4>
<h2>My Second Post</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin nulla neque, adipiscing vitae convallis in, varius vitae enim. Vestibulum sollicitudin eu justo id placerat. Donec viverra vestibulum dictum. Suspendisse potenti. Integer quis dolor luctus diam molestie blandit. Proin tristique lacus nec tellus euismod imperdiet. Fusce gravida in augue<a href='post.php?id=2'> .. Read more</a></p>
<p>Category: Uncatagorised</p>
</article>

<a href='index.php?p=2'>Next</a></div>
</body>
 </html>
```

I can't stop the menu from producing a staircase affect. The menu in a separate file works correctly.
Im thinking that something else is triggering it to do this. Thank you for your help. The idea is that the menu will look similar to the Facebook menu and be fixed to the top of the screen.

Comment: I used your code on jsfiddle, and for some reason I'm not getting the staircase effect: http://jsfiddle.net/VjF9p/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

[Fiddle of OP's code](http://jsfiddle.net/kMf5a)

The issue seems to result from erroneous `<li style="list-style: none"><br></li>` items between each `<li>`

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kMf5a/1/)**

Comment: I've added the entire page now. No matter what the screen size i use (even full screen) the menu appears to staircase.

Comment: @user3020920 Can you add the output HTML and not the generating PHP? It is a million time easier for anyone to run HTML vs having the deployment in place to debug PHP generated HTML

Comment: @user3020920 firstly, you have output HTML content before your body tag, this is bound to cause problems...can you put it in a jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @user3020920 Its staircasing because between each item you have '<li style="list-style: none"><br></li>' which as far as I can see, serves no purpose..see http://jsfiddle.net/kMf5a/1/

Comment: Don't know how i overlooked that so many times! thank you for your help!!I think I've shown this question as answered now